# Substituir PHP por Javascript e Node JS

Tags: php, javascript, html, node.js

É possível programar web totalmente sem **PHP**, usando **Javascript** e **Node JS**?
Além de Html e CSS claro;

Comment: Sim, utilizando Node com ExpressJS, AdonisJS ou até outros frameworks.

Comment: @AngeloSoares nem de frameworks precisa, em nodejs usando request e response criei um estrutura minimalista de rotas independente, e funciona muito bem sendo muito mais eficiente que os populares FWs, inclusive com regex (chamo de patterns lá) para rotas dinâmicas. Mas ótimo que citou os exemplos dos frameworks existentes.

Comment: Ajudaria se pudesse [edit] e fundamentar a pergunta (por ex: o que foi que tentou e não deu certo, a ponto de ter motivado a dúvida, até pelo fato de navegação na web existir e funcionar desde muito antes de PHP e Node), permitindo respostas objetivas e que não dependam de mera opinião. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Sim meu amigo! Totalmente viável, aliás! O que você deve entender é que no `frontend`, HTML, CSS e JavaScript **SEMPRE** estarão rodando no navegador. PHP e NodeJS são para fins de `backend`, apenas para tratar requisições e respostas, cujo estas são definidas conforme sua necessidade no frontend. Sua aplicação não precisa nem de backend (em certos casos), você pode utilizar algum tipo de serviço `BaaS` (Backend as a Service), onde você pode integrar uma espécie de backend dentro do front! Olha que legal! Um bom exemplo disso é o `Firebase`, o qual possibilita que você possa integrar um banco de dados dentro do frontend, sem a necessidade alguma de trabalhar em um backend para sua aplicação. Você pode ter uma aplicação totalmente baseada em JavaScript por exemplo, com o HTML, JS e CSS dentro de um único (ou vários) arquivos com a extensão `.JSX` (ou `.TSX`, caso você opte por usar TypeScript). Essa aplicação totalmente baseada em JavaScript, é fortemente usada quando você trabalha com `ReactJS`, uma biblioteca criada pelo Facebook, que permite que você crie uma aplicação voltada apenas para JavaScript. Porém, como dito antes, quando você roda um `build` dentro do ReactJS, ele irá gerar o HTML, CSS e JS de forma estática dentro de uma pasta, ou seja, o navegador não irá trabalhar com o ReactJS em si, mas sim, com os arquivos gerados por ele. Recomendo fortemente você estudar ReactJS integrando o Firebase dentro dele, você poderá criar aplicações se preocupando apenas com seu frontend, e sem ter a dor de cabeça de criar todo um backend para atender a demanda.

Comment: Caraca Felipe, muito obrigado cara, já abriu bastante minha mente e tirou várias dúvidas. Meu foco é realmente não usar PHP. Se tiver algum curso ou conteúdo pra indicar, deixa aqui. Fico grato mesmo. Terminei a faculdade há pouco tempo e agora quero me especializar.

Comment: A Cod3r oferece diversos cursos dentro da Udemy, recomendo o curso de Desenvolvimento Web Moderno deles, dentro deste ÚNICO curso, você poderá aprender diversos frameworks voltados para desenvolvimento web (inclusive, lá eles abordam o `React`). Mas não dependa apenas de cursos, sempre tente ler a documentação primeiro, é um bom hábito.